# How to successfully deploy Spring-XD in Yarn?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, spring-xd

I have a YARN Cluster with 2 nodes. I have validated the YARN cluster is running fine. I am trying to get XD deployed.

I followed the steps in latest XD guide a Configured Zk, Postgres, Redis and modified the servers.yml accordingly. No error messages after executing start commands. But I don't see any applications running in YARN after executing start admin and start container. Also didn't see anything in yarn `applicationDir` I configured.

```
java version "1.7.0_55"
OS version Linux 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux, RHEL 6.5
```

Also where can I see log messages?

Couple of general questions on install

Where should I copy YARN binaries? In any of the YARN cluster nodes? Or all of them? Or can I just copy in my local and just yarn-push will take care of the actual install?

Should the `applicationDir` be created on all YARN nodes or just on the Resource Manager?

If the XD guide can call out these explicitly, it will be great.

```
[jmupfnd@awsupfxdqa1nodejs1 bin]$ cd ..
[jmupfnd@awsupfxdqa1nodejs1 spring-xd-1.0.1.RELEASE-yarn]$ bin/xd-yarn push

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.7.RELEASE)

2014-12-01 09:07:54,799 INFO [ConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor] - No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2014-12-01 09:07:54,808 INFO [ConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor] - No bean named 'taskExecutor' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default SyncTaskExecutor will be created.
2014-12-01 09:07:55,856 INFO [SpringYarnConfiguration] - Enabling CLIENT for Yarn
2014-12-01 09:07:55,875 INFO [SpringYarnConfiguration] - We couldn't figure out if we could use existing configuration
2014-12-01 09:07:55,875 INFO [SpringYarnConfiguration] - Building configuration for bean 'yarnConfiguration'
2014-12-01 09:07:55,907 INFO [SpringYarnConfigBuilder] - Existing yarnConfiguration: null
2014-12-01 09:07:56,084 INFO [ConfigurationFactoryBean] - Overwriting fsUri=[file:///] with fsUri=[hdfs://10.94.70.3:8020]
2014-12-01 09:07:56,085 INFO [ConfigurationFactoryBean] - Overwriting rmAddress=[0.0.0.0:8032] with rmAddress=[10.94.70.3:8032]
2014-12-01 09:07:56,091 INFO [SpringYarnConfigBuilder] - Setting configuration for SpringYarnConfigs:  fs.defaultFS=hdfs://10.94.70.3:8020 yarn.resourcemanager.address=10.94.70.3:8032 Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml
2014-12-01 09:07:56,097 INFO [EnvironmentFactoryBean] - Adding CLASSPATH=./*
2014-12-01 09:07:56,431 WARN [NativeCodeLoader] - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2014-12-01 09:07:57,146 INFO [AbstractResourceLocalizer] - About to copy localized files
[jmupfnd@awsupfxdqa1nodejs1 spring-xd-1.0.1.RELEASE-yarn]$ ls -l data
total 0
[jmupfnd@awsupfxdqa1nodejs1 spring-xd-1.0.1.RELEASE-yarn]$ ls -l
total 124564
drwxr-xr-x 2 jmupfnd gjmupfnd      4096 Dec  1 08:57 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 jmupfnd gjmupfnd      4096 Dec  1 09:05 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 jmupfnd gjmupfnd       417 Oct  2 11:36 custom-modules.zip
drwxr-x--- 2 jmupfnd gjmupfnd      4096 Dec  1 08:56 data
drwxr-xr-x 2 jmupfnd gjmupfnd      4096 Oct  2 11:36 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 jmupfnd gjmupfnd     49114 Oct  2 11:07 LICENSE
-rw-r----- 1 jmupfnd gjmupfnd      7338 Dec  1 09:07 manifest.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 jmupfnd gjmupfnd      1456 Oct  2 11:07 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 jmupfnd gjmupfnd 127340310 Oct  2 11:36 spring-xd-yarn-1.0.1.RELEASE.zip
[jmupfnd@awsupfxdqa1nodejs1 spring-xd-1.0.1.RELEASE-yarn]$ ./bin/xd-yarn start admin

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.7.RELEASE)

2014-12-01 09:08:43,382 INFO [ConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor] - No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2014-12-01 09:08:43,403 INFO [ConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor] - No bean named 'taskExecutor' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default SyncTaskExecutor will be created.
2014-12-01 09:08:44,516 INFO [SpringYarnConfiguration] - Enabling CLIENT for Yarn
2014-12-01 09:08:44,530 INFO [SpringYarnConfiguration] - We couldn't figure out if we could use existing configuration
2014-12-01 09:08:44,531 INFO [SpringYarnConfiguration] - Building configuration for bean 'yarnConfiguration'
2014-12-01 09:08:44,556 INFO [SpringYarnConfigBuilder] - Existing yarnConfiguration: null
2014-12-01 09:08:44,734 INFO [ConfigurationFactoryBean] - Overwriting fsUri=[file:///] with fsUri=[hdfs://10.94.70.3:8020]
2014-12-01 09:08:44,735 INFO [ConfigurationFactoryBean] - Overwriting rmAddress=[0.0.0.0:8032] with rmAddress=[10.94.70.3:8032]
2014-12-01 09:08:44,741 INFO [SpringYarnConfigBuilder] - Setting configuration for SpringYarnConfigs:  fs.defaultFS=hdfs://10.94.70.3:8020 yarn.resourcemanager.address=10.94.70.3:8032 Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml
2014-12-01 09:08:44,748 INFO [EnvironmentFactoryBean] - Adding CLASSPATH=./*
2014-12-01 09:08:45,156 WARN [NativeCodeLoader] - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2014-12-01 09:08:46,043 INFO [AbstractYarnClient] - submitApplication, got applicationId=[application_1417028324995_0004]
2014-12-01 09:08:46,044 INFO [AbstractResourceLocalizer] - Setting stagingId=application_1417028324995_0004
2014-12-01 09:08:46,044 INFO [AbstractResourceLocalizer] - Marking distributed state false
2014-12-01 09:08:46,044 INFO [AbstractResourceLocalizer] - About to resolve localized files
[jmupfnd@awsupfxdqa1nodejs1 spring-xd-1.0.1.RELEASE-yarn]$ yarn application -list
14/12/01 09:09:03 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /10.94.70.3:8032
14/12/01 09:09:03 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Total number of applications (application-types: [] and states: [SUBMITTED, ACCEPTED, RUNNING]):0
                Application-Id      Application-Name        Application-Type          User       Queue               State         Final-State         Progress                        Tracking-URL
[jmupfnd@awsupfxdqa1nodejs1 spring-xd-1.0.1.RELEASE-yarn]$ ./bin/xd-yarn start container

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.7.RELEASE)

2014-12-01 09:09:44,199 INFO [ConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor] - No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2014-12-01 09:09:44,210 INFO [ConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor] - No bean named 'taskExecutor' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default SyncTaskExecutor will be created.
2014-12-01 09:09:45,307 INFO [SpringYarnConfiguration] - Enabling CLIENT for Yarn
2014-12-01 09:09:45,326 INFO [SpringYarnConfiguration] - We couldn't figure out if we could use existing configuration
2014-12-01 09:09:45,326 INFO [SpringYarnConfiguration] - Building configuration for bean 'yarnConfiguration'
2014-12-01 09:09:45,353 INFO [SpringYarnConfigBuilder] - Existing yarnConfiguration: null
2014-12-01 09:09:45,532 INFO [ConfigurationFactoryBean] - Overwriting fsUri=[file:///] with fsUri=[hdfs://10.94.70.3:8020]
2014-12-01 09:09:45,533 INFO [ConfigurationFactoryBean] - Overwriting rmAddress=[0.0.0.0:8032] with rmAddress=[10.94.70.3:8032]
2014-12-01 09:09:45,539 INFO [SpringYarnConfigBuilder] - Setting configuration for SpringYarnConfigs:  fs.defaultFS=hdfs://10.94.70.3:8020 yarn.resourcemanager.address=10.94.70.3:8032 Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml
2014-12-01 09:09:45,547 INFO [EnvironmentFactoryBean] - Adding CLASSPATH=./*
2014-12-01 09:09:45,940 WARN [NativeCodeLoader] - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2014-12-01 09:09:46,861 INFO [AbstractYarnClient] - submitApplication, got applicationId=[application_1417028324995_0005]
2014-12-01 09:09:46,861 INFO [AbstractResourceLocalizer] - Setting stagingId=application_1417028324995_0005
2014-12-01 09:09:46,862 INFO [AbstractResourceLocalizer] - Marking distributed state false
2014-12-01 09:09:46,862 INFO [AbstractResourceLocalizer] - About to resolve localized files
[jmupfnd@awsupfxdqa1nodejs1 spring-xd-1.0.1.RELEASE-yarn]$ yarn application -list
14/12/01 09:09:52 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /10.94.70.3:8032
14/12/01 09:09:52 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Total number of applications (application-types: [] and states: [SUBMITTED, ACCEPTED, RUNNING]):0
                Application-Id      Application-Name        Application-Type          User       Queue               State         Final-State         Progress                        Tracking-URL
[jmupfnd@awsupfxdqa1nodejs1 spring-xd-1.0.1.RELEASE-yarn]$
```

Comment: It's worth to check by listing using all states `yarn application -list -appStates ALL` or by using UI if any processes in YARN were actually started. If you don't see any YARN apps listed there then it'd be a good to see servers.yml config. If something was started but then failed you should have Appmaster/Container logs somewhere.

Comment: Now I could see that the processes failed, couldn't find anything in hadoop/logs folder. Where do the failure logs appear?

Comment: If it's normal hadoop setup then under `hadoop/logs/userlogs`. Could you post your servers.yml so that I could check it out.

Comment: # XD on YARN deployment configuration
#
# You can set properties here to override the defaults.
#

xd:
    adminServers: 1
    adminMemory: 512M
    containers: 3
    containerMemory: 512M
    container:
        groups: yarn

spring:
    yarn:
        applicationDir: /opt/nodejs/spring-xd-1.0.1.RELEASE-yarn/data

Comment: # Hadoop 2.2.x (hadoop22) and Hadoop 2.4.x (hadoop24):
spring:
    yarn:
        siteYarnAppClasspath: "$HADOOP_CONF_DIR,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*"
        siteMapreduceAppClasspath: "$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*"

Comment: # Hadoop properties
spring:
  hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://{IP}:8020
    resourceManagerHost: {IP}

Comment: zk:
  client:
     connect: {IP}:2181

Comment: #xd:
  transport: redis

Comment: spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://{IP}:5432/xdjob
    username: springxd
    password: xxxxxxx
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    validationQuery: select 1

Comment: spring:
  redis:
   port: 6379
   host: {IP}

Comment: SO is eating yaml indentation but are you sure you have a full `xd.transport` defined? It looks like xd part of it might still be commented out.

Comment: Use of {ip} is something you should avoid because it's never going to work in a real hadoop cluster when nodes are on a different hosts.

Comment: has it worked for you so far?

Comment: Is there any way to specify the yarn queue name, while deploying it on yarn using "yarn push/submit" commands?